# Create Image Slideshow with Html, Css & Jade

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

I'm trying to add an image slide show to a basic site. I'm using Node.js and jade as template engine.

The site crashes in local host with this message:

```
    TypeError: D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\views\layout.jade:42
    40|                     img.slide-images(src='/images/slide_four.jpg')

    41| 

  > 42|                 a.prev(onclick=plusSlide(-1)) &#10094;

    43|                 a.next(onclick=plusSlide(+1)) &#10095;

    44| 

    45|             .centered-indicators


     plusSlide is not a function
    at eval (eval at exports.compile (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:236:39)
    at eval (eval at exports.compile (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:306:22)
    at res (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:219:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:380:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:370:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render  
 (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render 

   (D:\Workspace\websites\actWebsite\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
```

My layout.jade file with the html code:

```
.container
        .carousel-container
            .mySlides.fade
                img.slide-images(src='/images/slide_one.jpg')
            .mySlides.fade
                img.slide-images(src='/images/slide_two.jpg')
            .mySlides.fade
                img.slide-images(src='/images/slide_three.jpg')
            .mySlides.fade
                img.slide-images(src='/images/slide_four.jpg')

            a.prev(onclick=plusSlide(-1)) &#10094;  // crash starts from here
            a.next(onclick=plusSlide(+1)) &#10095;

        .centered-indicators
            span.indicator(onclick=currentSlide(1))
            span.indicator(onclick=currentSlide(2))
            span.indicator(onclick=currentSlide(3))
            span.indicator(onclick=currentSlide(4))
    block content
```

This is my external js file code for handling slides:

```
var slideIndex = 1;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(n);
}

function showSlides(n){
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    let indicators = document.getElementsByClassName('indicators');

// if greater than total no of slides reset slide index to first slide
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    } else if (n < 1) { // reset slide index to length of all the slides
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }

    //loop thru the slides n remove their display ppty
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    for (i = 0; i < indicators.length; i++){
        indicators[i].className = indicators[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    indicators[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

}
```

Can someone please point out to me what the problem is with my slide_four image? 
I have linked the js file properly and al the functions are called but it crashes.
Imp:

```
doctype
   html
      head
         title #{title}
         link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/main.css')
         script(type='text/javascript', src='/public/scripts/carousel.js')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the function name like so ...

```
a.prev(onclick="plusSlide(-1)") &#10094;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but the images are not displaying. What went wrong?

Comment: Uh, sometimes you have to figure stuff out on your own.  :)